# Multiple action buttons with one event handler in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to have a variable number of identical actionButton()s on a page all handled by one observeEvent() function.

For example, in a variable-length table of tables, I'd like each interior table to have a button that links to more information on that table.

In standard HTML, you do this with a simple form, where you use a hidden input to designate the interior table number, like this:

```
<form ...>
  <input id="table_number" type="hidden" value="1"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Examine"/>
</form>
```

When a button is pressed, you can examine the hidden input to see which one it was.

Is there a way to do this in Shiny? The only solution I've come up with is to give each actionButton() it's own inputId. This requires a separate observeEvent() for each button. Those have to be created ahead of time, imposing a maximum number of buttons.

Comment: There's a `submitButton` in shiny too http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/submitbutton-demo.html

Comment: @PorkChop - thanks for the link. I had forgotten this one. But unfortunately, `submitButton` captures all the events on the entire page until you click it. In standard HTML it would only be the events in that button's `<form>` and you could have multiple forms on a page. I've realized that what I'm looking for is simply an `actionButton` with a value field that could assigned when the button is created and returned when the button is pressed. Instead, `actionButton` returns the number of times it's been clicked.

Comment: you can bind all your buttons to one event, with `eventReactive` or `observeEvent` note that these can have multiple events inside separated by comma. http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html

Comment: The requirement for multiple buttons with different ids seems to be related to the fact that Shiny doesn't like to have two input objects with the same id. It ignores all but the first one. I wonder if that's a javascript/document object model limitation or if it's specific to Shiny?

Comment: its not `shiny` that doesnt like inputs with the same ids its very standard for `html` to have unique `id` on one page

Comment: Standard HTML allows you to have multiple `forms` on one page and each form can use the same id for something like `table_number`, as in the example above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It only took me a couple of years, but I now have a much better answer to this question. You can use a JavaScript/jQuery function to put an on-click event handler on every button in a document, then use the *Shiny.onInputChange()* function to pass the ID of a button (`<button id="xxx"...`) that has been clicked to a single observer in your Shiny code.

There's a full description with code examples at [One observer for all buttons in Shiny using JavaScript/jQuery](http://www.open-meta.org/technology/one-observer-for-all-buttons-in-shiny-using-javascriptjquery/)

Comment: This should get a hundred upvotes. Very helpful and easy to integrate! Thanks!

Comment: Should `observeEvent(input$js.button_clicked, ...` in one module be triggered by button clicks of inputs defined in a separate module?

Comment: @Giovanni - Sorry, I don't use modules so I'm not entirely sure of the answer to your question. Can you just leave the function in your main code, where it works really well?

Comment: Yep. That’s what I’m doing currently. I was just hoping this solution would be compatible with shiny modules.

Comment: I haven't tested it with modules, so I don't know either way. By the way, in the link to the full description of the method in the above answer, note that there's a link within the answer to a newer version of the JavaScript (and a link within that update to yet another, less important, update.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use shiny modules for this: you can have variable number of `actionButton` that are identical. These are defined in the `ab_moduleUI` part. They are handled by their own `observeEvent` but it has to be defined only once in the `ab_module` part.

With `lapply` any number of `actionButton` can be created.

Edit: You don't have to specify the number of buttons beforehand: use `renderUI` to generate UI elements at server side.

For demonstration purposes I added a `numericInput` to increase/decrease the number of modules to render.

```
# UI part of the module
ab_moduleUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      actionButton(ns("btn"), paste("ActionButton", id, sep="-")),
      textOutput(ns("txt"))
    )
  )
}

# Server part of the module
ab_module <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$btn,{
    output$txt <- renderText("More information shown")
  })
}


# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # lapply(paste0("mod", 1:no_btn), ab_moduleUI)
  numericInput("num", "Number of buttons to show" ,value = 5, min = 3, max = 10),
  uiOutput("ui")
)

# Server side
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$num, {
    output$ui <- renderUI({
      lapply(paste0("mod", 1:input$num), ab_moduleUI)
    })

    lapply(paste0("mod", 1:input$num), function(x) callModule(ab_module, x))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Read more about shiny modules [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

Comment: GdY - Thanks for this. I haven't used modules before and will study this more thoroughly. But on first look it appears to be pretty much what I'm already doing - giving each button its own id, then using their unique ids to figure out which button was pressed. This does work, but you have to specify the maximum number of buttons (`no_btn`) when you run Shiny, whereas I don't know the maximum number I'll need until the user loads some data (citations downloaded from PubMed/Embase/Cochrane etc., in my case). Standard HTML handles this so easily, I thought I was missing something.

Comment: Just edited the answer. I think this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes. After reading the information you suggested, I think you're right - namespace conflict (multiple objects with the same id) seems to be the problem, and modules appear to be the answer. Thanks for the time you spent on this!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the use of Shiny modules to answer my original question...

What I'd like to have is a way to have multiple buttons on a page that can be handled by a single `observeEvent()`, which is easy to do with traditional HTML forms, as shown in the original question.

GyD's demonstration code using Shiny modules almost solves the problem, but it doesn't actually return which button was pressed to the main server. It took me a long time, but I finally figured out how to write a module that does let the main server know which button was pressed:

```
actionInput <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   tagList(
      textInput(ns("text"), label=NULL, value=id),
      actionButton(ns("button"), "OK")
   )
}

action <- function(input, output, session) {
   eventReactive(input$button, {
      return(input$text)
   })
}

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(4, actionInput("b1")),
                         column(4, actionInput("b2")),
                         column(4, uiOutput("result"))))

server <-function(input, output, session) {
   b1 <- callModule(action, "b1")
   observeEvent(b1(), {
      output$result = renderText(b1())
   })
   b2 <- callModule(action, "b2")
   observeEvent(b2(), {
      output$result = renderText(b2())
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(In a real application, I would make the `textInputs` invisible, as they're only there to provide an id for which button was pressed.)

This solution still requires an `observeEvent()` in the main server for each button. It may be possible to use modules in some other way to solve the problem, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

My original alternative, using a separate `observeEvent()` in the main server for each button, is actually quite a bit simpler than an expansion of this demo code would be for a hundred or more buttons.